# Using ajax in a specific case in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I created a dropdown login form so when the login is successful the user will be redirected to the root path, otherwise the dropdown form will be updated with an error message without reloading the entire page. In order to do that I used AJAX to display the error message, my problem is that when the login is successful it doesn't redirect to the root path. I want to use AJAX only in the else case within the controller method. Thanks in advance.
This is my code so far:

```
// Controller
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path}
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
//View 
<div class="dropdown-menu login">   
<%= form_tag sessions_path, remote: true do%>
.
.
.
```

---

```
//Jquery Script
  $( ".login").prepend("<p class='loginerror'>Wrong user/password</p>")
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request is ajax ( remote: true ), your response will be js.

So you need to redirect with js:

```
render js: "window.location.href = '#{my_named_route_path}'"
```

controller:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render js: "window.location.href = '#{my_named_route_path}'"
  end
end
```

This will render `create.js` if the condition is false, you don't need `redirect_to` if your request is ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, In both cases `JS` request is being sent. try this

```
// Controller
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
  respond_to do |format|
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    format.html { redirect_to root_path}
    format.js
  else
    format.html { redirect_to root_path}
    format.js { render js: "window.location.href=#{root_url}" }
  end
end
```